# How to use a WEKA model in Java for a real time prediction task?

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

I have trained and loaded a WEKA model into my Java program and I am trying to use it for a real-time predictive task.

I have searched online and the resources/documentation I have found involve using a pre-generated set of test instances to pass into the model.

However, in my case the data is generated on the fly in my Java program and I was wondering how I would pass the feature set into the model in an acceptable format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several sources on how to create dataset structures on-the-fly in Weka:

- Chapter *18.3 Creating datasets in memory* in the Weka manual
- `CreateInstances.java` example class contained in the `wekaexamples.zip` archive that comes with your Weka download
- [Creating ARFF file](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/creating_arff_file/) article on the [Weka wiki](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/)

At prediction time, you can simply create `weka.core.Instance` (`weka.core.DenseInstance` or `weka.core.SparseInstance`) objects and pass them into the model.

However, these still need access to the dataset structure (ie the `weka.core.Instances` object), as the model may query the dataset structure. Simply assign the dataset structure that the model was trained with using the `setDataset(Instances)` method.

Weka serializes both, model and dataset header, by default, so you can just reuse that header as your dataset structure when loading a serialized model.